# Is it thread safe to use Spring Data JPA repository inside Java 8 forEach loop?

Tags: java, spring, java-8, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

May I use Spring Data JPA repository inside Java 8 forEach loop? Is it thread safe?

```
public interface MajorModOptRepository extends CrudRepository<MajorModOpt, Long> {
    Set<MajorModOpt> findManyByManCodeAndModCode(String manCode, String modCode);
}
```

And here is the forEach loop:

```
@Component
public class MajorModOptsHelper {

    @Autowired
    private MajorModOptRepository majorModOptRepository;

    public void setMajorOpts(@NonNull List<Vehicle> vehicles) {
        vehicles.forEach(this::setMajorOpts);

    }

    // This method is called by above forEach
    public void setMajorOpts(Vehicle vehicle) {
        ...
        // Repository method is called here
        Set<MajorModOptVO> knownOpts = majorModOptRepository.findManyByManCodeAndModCode(vehicle.getManCode(), vehicle.getModCode());
        ...
    }
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: There is no multi-threading involved when calling `forEach` on a collection. The only thing to keep in mind is that certain collections, like `ArrayList` or `HashSet` must not be modified while iterating, but this is the same when using an `Iterator` based `for` loop.

Comment: It's thread safe. But nevertheless, I'm more attracted by a helluwa bad thing you're about to do. And that's just invoking `findManyByManCodeAndModCode` method within that `forEach`. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is tread save. There is no multi-threading involved.

*The only thing you should take care about, is not to open an new transaction for each single `findManyByManCodeAndModCode` (except you want it). The most easy way to solve this, it to add an `@Transactional` to your `setMajorOpts(@NonNull List<Vehicle> vehicles)` method.*

Comment: Even worse. He's firing that repository method in `forEach` which is basically equivalent to `N+1` issue.

Comment: @Branislav Lazic:You are right, but the scope of that question was threading and maybe threading like issues. Performance was not in the scope of that question. **I think your comment is worthwhile,**. Anyway meaningful justification on performance issues can been done only with knowledge about the context. For example: if the list of vehicles has typical just 2 or 3 items, than any optimization on hat is likely premature wasting of time.

Comment: If I add @Transactional on class MajorModOptsHelper then a transaction would be opened with each call to method setMajorOpts, correct? Which would be exactly what you warned of. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Either with your current `forEach` implementation or with a traditional `for-loop` your code is thread-safe.

You should worry about transactional boundaries instead (implemented programmatically or via `@Transactional` demarcation) since conceptually you are splitting the `List<Vehicle>` `save` operation into two methods. What should happen if one of the `Vehicle` `save` operation fails? With the default [Propagation.REQUIRED](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/annotation/Propagation.html#REQUIRED) the whole operation will be rolled back whereas if your second per-Vehicle `save` operation is of [Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/annotation/Propagation.html#REQUIRES_NEW) then all the previous pre-failure `Vehicle`s would have made it through (= committed).

Comment: In fact, the only thing you should be worried about here is the use of field injection (bad) rather than constructor injection (right).

Comment: A simple `@Transactional` annotation at `setMajorOpts(@NonNull List<Vehicle> vehicles)` or a more outer method that build a block around the unit of work will solve that problem.

Comment: @Engineer Dollery - agreed. But it's not the only thing to be concerned about. Transactional boundaries is important here according to the OP's presented code.

Comment: For any real use, yeah, but you never know, transactional boundaries just might not be important here, or may be handled in the controller invoking this code in the first place.

Comment: I'v found nice article on topic mentioned by @EngineerDollery:  http://vojtechruzicka.com/field-dependency-injection-considered-harmful/